# Oracle 12c - Insufficient Privileges When Trying To Create A Trigger With SYS User

Tags: oracle, permissions, trigger, oracle-12c, sys

I want to create a trigger for CRE schema. I'm trying to create this trigger with SYS user but I have insufficient privileges error.

My trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CRE.TRIGGER_NAME
AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
DECLARE
asd1 NUMBER;
asd2 NUMBER;
asd3 NUMBER;
asd4 NUMBER;
asd NUMBER;
qwe VARCHAR2(200);
qaz VARCHAR2(200);
ewq NUMBER;
zaq VARCHAR2(50);
xsw VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
CRE.SOME_PROCEDURE_NAME('S', SYSDATE);
END;
/
```

How can it possible with SYS user?

How can I fix it?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you create the trigger as `SYS`, the owner must have the `CREATE TRIGGER` privilege:

`GRANT CREATE TRIGGER TO CRE;`

In addition to the above, to create an `AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE` trigger, the `ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER` privilege is also required:

`GRANT ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER TO CRE;`

Answer (score 0):

Can the **CRE** account execute the "SOME_PROCEDURE_NAME" procedure?

You are creating a trigger that will be owned by the user CRE and, by default, it will be created with [DEFINER Rights](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/1574831/Definer-and-Invoker-Rights-for-stored-routines-in-Oracle.htm#:%7E:text=A%20routine%20stored%20in%20the,process%20logic%20in%20one%20place).

Anything and everything that you want to do within that trigger must be "possible" by the CRE user itself and any such permissions must be granted *directly* to the user.  It *cannot* gain these permissions through the application of Roles (because the account exists independently of any Roles that it may or may not be granted to it).

Comment: While this is true, this would result in a different error, and the trigger could be created without it, it just could not be compiled. Also `CRE` does not need extra privilege to execute its on procedure.